# enter key and onclick together

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

I have a login form. the form gets the mobile number and sends it with ajax for the verification code. my code works right but many users after writing their mobile number, they press enter key not click on the button. the event I write is onclick not keydown or keyup. how I can relate these events.

the HTML :

```
  <form class="modal-content animate" id="tel_form">

  <h6>insert your mobile number </h6>




  <label>mobile number : </label>
  <input type="text" id="tel_input"  required>

  <button type="button" id="tel_button">send</button>
</form>
```

the javascript :

```
var tel = document.getElementById('tel_button');

tel.onclick = function(){
var tel_number = document.getElementById('tel_input').value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304){
            if(xhr.response == 1){
alert('done');

}else{
 alert('wrong')
  }
}
} 

xhr.open('post' , "<?php echo base_url('login/auth/');?>" , true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send("tel_number= " + tel_number);
}
```

when the user clicks the send button everything is right but when the user press enter key the page reloaded and I do not want to be reloaded I want to have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'onClick' event, You could use 'onsubmit' event and also change the type of your button from 'button' to 'submit' as below:

```js
var formSubmitted = function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var tel_number = document.getElementById('tel_input').value;
  console.log(tel_number);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304) {
        if (xhr.response == 1) {
          alert('done');

        } else {
          alert('wrong')
        }
      }
    }

    xhr.open('post', "<?php echo base_url('login/auth/');?>", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("tel_number= " + tel_number);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="formSubmitted()" class="modal-content animate" id="tel_form">

  <h6>insert your mobile number </h6>




  <label>mobile number : </label>
  <input type="text" id="tel_input"  required>

  <button type="submit" id="tel_button">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i have multiple modal for login and in the first function i load the second modal. it works when i click the button because i write on click EventListener. but when i press enter key instead of clicking, it reloads my page and i lose the second modal

Comment: you can use event.preventDefault(); from beginning of the method to prevent page reload, I change the code to prevent the reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce Keyup event listener to your input tag.

```
var input = document.getElementById("tel_input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          // Trigger the button element with a click
          document.getElementById("tel_button").click();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks it works . but we have to enters on keyboard . what is the second enter's KeyCode?

Comment: what do you mean by second enter?

Comment: the second enter on numpad

Comment: you got the answer?

Comment: the event.preventDefault() not works . the page reload again but the onclick event run

Comment: i have multiple modal for login and in the first function i load the second modal. it works when i click the button because i write on click EventListener. but when i press enter key instead of clicking, it reloads my page and i lose the second modal

Answer (score 0):

You should change button type from `button` to `submit` or you can write your `keyup` event listener and then run the code when enter is pressed and you would add `onsubmit="myScript"` attribute in your form tag also.